# SQL Server : INSERT works from Visual Studio locally but not on web server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have the following `INSERT` statement:

```
Dim SQLstr As String = "INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetail (SysOrg, oID, pID, Qty, UntPrice) 
                        VALUES ('" + sOrg + "','" + oID + "','" + pID + "','" + pQty + "',(CONVERT(Decimal,'" + pPrice + "')))"
```

It works fine in Visual Studio. But throws an error on the web server:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

My connection string is connecting to the same remote database. What can I do?

Comment: What are the database datatypes of the columns `SysOrg,oID,pID,Qty,UntPrice`. At the very least you should investigate (and post) that. Are you inserting the same data? Are the datatypes the same in both databases?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Your problem will probably go away with parameters ... but as to why this happens, maybe you have some locale issues, like if your SQL Server is in Europe it might expect those funny European numbers like `100.000.000,99`

Comment: There is only one Database, being accessed from both local as well as site apps. Turns out, from local machine, UntPrice (type decimal) was ok receiving a 'comma' in the decimal point place, but for some mysterious reason from the site it did not like that, but demanded a full stop. I still don't know why? But at least the system works now :-)
Thank you all who contributed thus far.